# Linker Errors when Building Shared Library with LLVM and C++

Tags: xcode, shared-libraries, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to build a shared library using C++ and LLVM. The goal is to generate LLVM IR from an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) representation of a programming language. However, I'm getting linker errors during the build process. I think these errors are related to the LLVM libraries, but I'm having trouble resolving them. Here's the command I'm using to build the shared library

```
g++ -shared -o libNodeBridge.dylib Compiler/bridge/bridge/JavaBridge.cpp Compiler/bridge/token/Token.cpp Compiler/bridge/parser/ParseTokenToAst.cpp Compiler/llvm_codegen/LLVMCodeGen.cpp \
$(/Users/kagelol/_development/Compiler/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags) -frtti \
-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin
```

When I try to build the shared library, I'm getting the following linker errors:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext(), referenced from:
      LLVMCodeGen::LLVMCodeGen() in LLVMCodeGen-76e962.o
  llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext(), referenced from:
      LLVMCodeGen::~LLVMCodeGen() in JavaBridge-773828.o
  ...
```

I'm using Xcode and have included necessary header and library paths in dev env. I suspect that the issue might be related to the way I'm linking against the LLVM libraries, but I'm not sure what exactly is causing the problem.

-What could be causing these linker errors related to llvm::LLVMContext, llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext(), and other related symbols?
-Are there any additional linker flags or libraries that I need to include when building the shared library with LLVM?
-Is there a step I might be missing in configuring Xcode for proper linking against the LLVM libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Providing path to libraries is not enough, that is just a path that linker will use to find your library, if you are linking against that library and currently you are not. In your case you need to link against `core` library.

The best way to resolve this is to use `llvm-config`.

For example if you invoke:
`llvm-config --libs core` it will give you something like this: `-lLLVM-16`, so if you add this to your `g++` command it will work.

To make this work with future `llvm` versions, simply update the part of your command that uses `llvm-config`:

```bash
g++ -shared -o libNodeBridge.dylib Compiler/bridge/bridge/JavaBridge.cpp Compiler/bridge/token/Token.cpp Compiler/bridge/parser/ParseTokenToAst.cpp Compiler/llvm_codegen/LLVMCodeGen.cpp \
$(/Users/kagelol/_development/Compiler/bin/llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core) -frtti ...
```

Note this part:
`llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core`